# MySql COUNT(*) returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a sql-query to get the number of users of each group and sort all groups by them. But unfortunately, sql thinks that `user_count` is 1 when in fact it must be 0. If the number of users is greater than 0, it takes the correct value.

Here is my sql query:

```
SELECT G.id, COUNT(*) user_count
FROM groups G LEFT JOIN
     users U
     ON G.id = U.group_id
GROUP BY G.id
ORDER BY user_count
```

In `groups` table i have group ids in the field `id` and in `users` table i have users with their group ids in the field `group_id`

I'm not so good in SQL, so maybe i'm making some very stupid mistakes. Thank you in advance if you can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(*)` counts *rows*.  You want to count matches, so count from the second table:

```
SELECT G.id, COUNT(u.group_id) as user_count
. . .
```

In other words, the `LEFT JOIN` returns a row when there is no match.  That row has a `NULL` value for all the columns in the `users` table.

Comment: @SergeyShcherbakov . . . To a native English speaker, the question is pretty clearly about the 1 versus 0 in the count.  The OP already *has* a query that does the other things.  The question is about the values in the rows.  As for your first comment, it is simply wrong.  The OP simply needs to replace the `COUNT(*)` expression with the `COUNT(u.group_id)` in this answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I see my mistake now.